# Could not load type 'HelloSign.Client' from assembly 'HelloSign, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hellosign-api

I am working with hello sign.

could you please figure out where the problem is. I have searched a lot but didn't find same.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendDocument(SendDocumentForm Form)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            SendDocumentFormViewModel model = new SendDocumentFormViewModel();
            model.Form = Form;
            return View(model);
        }

        var client = new Client(HelloSignAPIKey);
        var request = new SignatureRequest();
        request.Subject = Form.Subject;
        request.Message = Form.Message;
        request.AddSigner(Form.SignerEmail, Form.SignerName);
        byte[] arreglo = new byte[Form.File.ContentLength];
        Form.File.InputStream.Read(arreglo, 0, Form.File.ContentLength);
        request.AddFile(arreglo, Form.File.FileName);
        request.TestMode = true;
        var response = client.CreateEmbeddedSignatureRequest(request, HelloSignClientID);
        var urlSign = client.GetSignUrl(response.Signatures[0].SignatureId);
        return RedirectToAction("Sign", new { url = urlSign.SignUrl });
    }
```

[Here is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4c9i.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your unable to load the HelloSign C# SDK.

As far as your error:
Could not load type 'HelloSign.Client' from assembly 'HelloSign, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

It looks like the SDK is not loading properly.
https://github.com/HelloFax/hellosign-dotnet-sdk

Try to make a direct RestSharp call to the HelloSign API
http://restsharp.org/